# sending data to url from foreach to pass in the variable in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

sending data from foreach which is in the view 'header' in the url using json encode but the value is not passing to the variable and showing empty value in the controller 'user'
here is the code

'header'(view)

```
<?php  foreach ($data as $key ):?>

    <?php echo anchor('user/dashboard/?data='.json_encode($key)  ,'Home'); ?><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></li>
```

now the controller 'user'

```
$data=json_decode($_GET['data']);
  print_r($data);
  $this->load->model('Pmodel'); 
 $email['data']=$this->Pmodel->select_model($data);

   $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard',$email);
```

now when it goes to the controller it shows error

```
http://localhost/P_Display/user/dashboard/?data={
```

no value in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look source document. Link is ok but is no good format html:

```
<a href="user/dashboard/?data="key3"">Home</a>
```

You must use urlencode:

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$value ) {
    echo anchor('user/dashboard/?data='.urlencode(json_encode($key)),'Home');
}
```

And

```
$data=json_decode(urldecode($_GET['data']));
print_r($data);
$this->load->model('Pmodel'); 
$email['data']=$this->Pmodel->select_model($data);

$this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard',$email);
```

Or you can use serialize (php).

:)